# Combination Frequency Between 2 Columns in Excel

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

Essentially, I have a dataset consisting of two columns as seen below. I am looking for each unique route & the number of times it has show up in the dataset.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| JFK | LGA |
| JFK | NEW |
| LGA | JFK |
| NEW | JFK |
| NJJ | RKK |
| RKK | LGA |

Note: I do not want routes to be overcounted. Meaning, for instance JFK to LGA & LGA to JFK is the same route. So they should be counted together 2.

I tried using Pivot Tables but the issue is that it counts twice. Meaning, when you use pivot tables, the results show JFK to LGA as 1 & then LGA to JFK as 1. As opposed to showing them together.

In addition, my dataset is very huge, so using formulas using the name of each route is not possible (over 50K).EDIT: I think I put 5OK as a typo. I meant 5K.

EDIT: A desired solution would look like as follows:

| Column A | Column B | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JFK | LGA | 2 |
| JFK | NEW | 2 |
| NJJ | RKK | 1 |
| RKK | LGA | 1 |

If a python solution exists, happy to try that as well.

Comment: I don't understand your logic.  If `JFK-LGA` and `LGA-JFK` are the same, shouldn't they be counted as `1`? You write *`So they should be counted together 2`* Perhaps you should show a sample of your expected results given your posted data.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Michiel van der Blonk that 50,000 rows doesn't seem beyond the reach of a formula-based solution.

```
=LET(
    φ, BYROW(A2:B6, LAMBDA(ω, TEXTJOIN("|", , SORT(ω, , , 1)))),
    UNIQUE(HSTACK(φ, MAP(φ, LAMBDA(κ, SUM(N(φ = κ))))))
)
```

is one example, assuming data in `A2:B6`.

The output can of course be amended such that airport codes are returned to separate columns, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

50K doesn't seem like a number that Excel can't handle. However, if you still have problems with the amount you can try to load the data into Power Query. This is Excel's solution to big data. In Power Query you can make a custom column with a  formula like

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "TRAJ", each if [P1] < [P2] then [P1]&[P2] else [P2]&[P1])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Combination Frequency Between Two Columns

[image]

**Spills**

```
=LET(data1,A2:A11,data2,B2:B11,dlm,"@",
    lr,data1&dlm&data2,
    d,VSTACK(lr,data2&dlm&data1),
BYROW(lr,LAMBDA(r,COUNT(SEARCH(r,d)))))
```

**Copy Down**

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,A2,B$2:B$11,B2)+COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,B2,B$2:B$11,A2)
```

**Spills (Excel Table)**

```
=COUNTIFS([First],[@First],[Second],[@Second])+COUNTIFS([First],[@Second],[Second],[@First])
```